# azure deployment and on-premises authentication

Tags: azure, asp.net, single-sign-on

I'm developing an app that will eventually be deployed to the cloud. Right now I'm trying to get deployment to work, because I need to test HTTP callbacks that an outside service makes on my application.

Everything runs fine in my dev environment, but on deployment, it's redirecting to localhost for some reason. We're using an on-premises ADFS server for single-sign-on. Most of the stack-overflow and forum posts are either unanswered, or don't apply to specific use-case, so any help here would be appreciated.

I don't have anything hard-coded to point at LocalHost (I've double checked by searching the whole project), so I'm not sure where to go. Am I missing something from the azure setup?

Cross post from:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250620/asp-net-azure-deployment-and-on-premises-authentication

I've tried doing the right-click publish in Visual Studio, as well as setting up the Azure app server to deploy from Github. Don't have a ton of sysadmin background, so any insight would be appreciated.

Using Asp.net 4.6.1, MVC 5, and VS2015 Community Edition.

Comment: What is redirecting to localhost?  can you show some examples of what calls are being made and the result?

Comment: Are you deploying to a WebApp in Azure? Are you integrating authentication with Azure AD? if you are you might find that the APP URI or the APP login URL is pointing to Localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out we needed to add an endpoint to the adfs instance, as wReply gets ignored, unless it's added as a valid endpoint.